# How exactly did agréer invert in French?

Tags: étymologie

*agréer* flipped the subject and direct object like [like (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/like#etymonline_v_9510) and [please (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/please?ref=etymonline_crossreference), correct? But what were the steps? I'm guessing French commenced with

1. Mes desiderata m'agréent.

Syntactically how did this invert into

2. J'agrée avec mes desiderata.

#### agree

> [14] Originally, if a thing ‘agreed you’, it
> was to your liking, it pleased you. This early
> meaning survives in the adjective agreeable
> [14], but the verb has meanwhile moved on via
> ‘to reconcile (people who have quarrelled)’ and
> ‘to come into accord’ to its commonest present-day
> sense, ‘to concur’. It comes from Old French
> *agréer* ‘to please’, which was based on the
> phrase *a gré* ‘to one’s liking’. *Gré* was
> descended from Latin *grātum*, a noun based on
> *grātus* ‘pleasing’, from which English also gets
> grace and grateful.
> → CONGRATULATE, GRACE, GRATEFUL,
> GRATITUDE

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 13.

Comment: See ex. 28-36 [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agr%C3%A9er); that's only but one way this verb works. It's not necessarily the most casual verb really.

Comment: *Agréer* is quite rare as @Amande already commented, I believe I never used that verb outside in the *Veuillez agréer...* letter ending. *Desiderata* is quite rare too. I guess the number of times I used that word in my whole life is less than the number of fingers in my hands. *Agréer avec ses desiderata* is then probably an expression there is zero chance for someone to say spontaneously, not to mention the bizarre tautology *I agree with my wishes*...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the *"agréer"* verb translates as :

1. Pronoun and verb or infinitive verb followed by a direct or indirect object : giving agreement/expressing convenience regarding the object. Example: "J'agrée à ses dires", "Ayant agréer les termes du contrat, ..."
2. Non pronoun subject and verb followed by a direct or indirect object : subject gives an agreement/expresses convenience regarding the object. Example: "John agrée à cette condition", "Martin agrée les dires de Steven".
3. Subject followed by a **personal pronoun** then verb : Subject pleases or is liked by the one designed by the personal pronoun *or* the one designed by the personal pronoun expresses liking / convenience regarding the subject. Example "Cela m'agrée", "Ce voyage t'agrée tant que ça ?" and indeed "Mes desiderata m'agréent.". Here, the personal pronoun gives a possessive means to the sentence and by this way gives to the verb "agréer" its original meanings expressing liking/convenience.

Thus, the invert for this verb in french has to keep the original meanings. In the case 3 and then your examples, it has to express the accordance with own (or subject) personal desire.

In the case "Mes desiderata m'agréent.", we have a subject *"Mes desiderata"*, a possessive pronoun *"m'"* which means "to me / for me" and the verb.

The first step is to rephrase the sentence as it can be expressed in the form "Mes desiderata agréent à moi." where the personal pronoun become an indirect object.

The second  step is then to conjugate the verb according to the indirect object as a subject : "J'agrée".

The last step is just to make the original subject as the new direct or indirect object : "J'agrée avec mes desiderata".